# Display the lines of file that contain the pattern 'Pap' but they don't contain the pattern 'Aig'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How to make such a double query ?
I try `grep -e Pap -e -v Aig filename.txt` and `grep 'Pap' && -v 'Aig' filename.txt`
but both don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pipe between your filters

```
grep -e Pap filename.txt | grep -v Aig
```